# not able to understand behaviour of ** operator

Tags: python

I have suddenly came across this, I am not able to understand why this is happening!

On python prompt,
using the `**` operator on 3 onwards like below giving wrong result.
i.e.,

```
>>> 2**2**2
16
>>> 3**3**3
7625597484987L
>>> 4**4**4
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096L
```

Then i thought i must have to use parentheses, so i used it and it is giving correct result.

```
>>>(3**3)**3
19683
```

BUT the `//` operator is supporting and giving correct results
    in this kind of operations, that is

```
>>> 4//4//4
0
>>> 40//4//6
1
```

please help me to understand.

Comment: What did you expect `4 ** 256` to return?

Comment: `**` is behaving according to the documentation. Always consult the documentation if you find unexpected behaviour. Section 5.4 at http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/expressions.html

Comment: thanks for the docs link. I am now clear on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `**` operator is right-associative, meaning `3**3**3` evaluates as `3**27` and `4**4**4` as `4**256`.

Comment: thanks a lot. But then // operator must be left associative ??

Comment: I don't know what the `//` operator is supposed to do, but if it returns the correct result, then yes.  :)

Comment: `//` is the floor-division operator. It is left-associative (which makes sense, since arithmetically 10/5/2 == 1 and not 4).

Answer (score 9):

`**` is right-associative. Mathematically, this makes sense: 3<sup>3<sup>3</sup></sup> is equal to 3<sup>27</sup>, not 27<sup>3</sup>.

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) states that it is right-associative:

> In an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left.

Comment: Actually, I think that line of documentation is just clarifying how the power-vs.-unary-operators rule in that section and the right-associative rule for power and comparisons in 5.15 interact. But I'm not sure about that. And either way, it's probably the clearest statement in the docs that the OP should expect exactly what he's seeing.

Comment: @abarnert: yep, as you say, that line of documentation is not authoritative. It's simply a way of summarizing the implications of the grammatical definition.

Comment: I think it is written on **section 5.4 of docs titled " The power operator"** on second paragraph (just after the example). **It is written "Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): -1**2 results in -1."**

Answer (score 3):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) say:

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for comparisons… and exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

In other words, `**` is right-associative, while `//` (like all other operators except comparisons) is left-associative.

Elsewhere, there's a whole section on [The power operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) that, after giving a rule (which isn't relevant here) about how power and unary operators interacts, clarifies that:

> [I]n an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left…

This is actually the way most programming languages do it.

Exponentiation isn't written with symmetrical operator syntax in mathematics, so there's really no reason it should have the same default associativity. And right-associative exponentiation is much less useful, because `(2**3)**4` is exactly the same thing as `2**(3*4)`, whereas there's nothing obvious that's the same thing as `2**(3**4)`.

Comment: I think you meant ..."and *left*-associative exponentiation is much less useful"...

Answer (score 1):

When you do stuff like `4**4**4`, you should use parentheses to make your intentions explicit.  The parser will resolve the ambiguity, as @cHao indicated, but it is confusing to others.  You should use `(4**4)**4` or `4**(4**4)`.  Explicit here is better than implicit, since taking powers of powers is not exactly a workaday operation we see all of the time.

Comment: yes of course I understand that I must use parentheses but just to know and also I saw differences between ** and // so just got curious!  Any way Thanks a lot